# Peerjs: on connection not working on safari and iOS

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, peerjs

This code work fine on android and pc
But not working on Safari and iOS

```
myPeer.on('connection', (conn) => {
                console.log("connection");
                conn.on('data', (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
```

On safari I get this error:

```
ERROR – "PeerJS: " – "Error:" – "(TypeError) Attempted to assign to readonly property."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem fixed in `peerjs@1.3.2` version